# Additional Information in ModelSerializer are not in used Model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem similar to this one: [Additional (non model) fields in ModelSerializer](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/840)

I want to create a object with a modelserializer like this:

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(source="username")
    password = serializers.CharField()
    password2 = serializers.WritableField() 
    ...

    class Meta:
         model = User
     fields = ('user', "password", "password2", ...)
```

Obviously, I am not interested in saving password2, it's just for the reason of comparison.

Ideally this should do the trick but for reasons, its not working as expected:

```
def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
    tags = attrs.pop('password2', None)
    obj = super(CreateUserSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
    obj.tags = tags
    logging.info(u"Object gets restored, field 'password2' gets removed,  list with arguments for object: {0}".format(tags))
    return obj
```

The Error I am getting is:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'password2'
 ...
 /home/jan/projekte/alarmapp/eclipse_workspace/AlarmServer/AlarmApp/src/external/rest_framework/fields.py in get_component

55. val = getattr(obj, attr_name)
```

Any Idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [this small Gist](https://gist.github.com/allieus/7674459) should be helpful:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_password2(self, attrs, source):
        password2 = attrs.pop(source)
        if attrs['password'] != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('password mismatch')
        return attrs

    def to_native(self, obj):
        self.fields.pop('password2')
        return super(CreateUserSerializer, self).to_native(obj)

    class Meta:
        model = User
```